# Multiple Rx 404 errors in Angular2 component

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have added a script reference to the RXjs library as well as including an import statement to the Rx root.

In my HTML:

```
<script src="libs/Rx.js"></script>
<script>
    System.config({
        map: {
            rxjs: '/libs/Rx' // added this map section
        },
        packages: {
            scripts: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

(I use Gulp to transfer the node_modules I need to a libs folder. This is something I needed to do to get Angular2 to work in Visual Studio 2015, as described in [Starting Angular 2 in ASP.NET 5 with TypeScript using Visual Studio 2015](http://www.mithunvp.com/angular-2-in-asp-net-5-typescript-visual-studio-2015/).)

In my component:

```
import "rxjs/Rx";
```

I am getting these errors.

```
.../Rx/Observable 404 (Not Found)
.../Rx/Subject 404 (Not Found)
.../RX/operator/toPromise 404 (Not Found)
.../Rx/observable/PromiseObservable 404 (Not Found)
.../Rx/operators/map 404 (Not Found)
```

These were raised by system.src.js (line 4868). Why is Systemjs unable to find them? The Rx.js file has these defined.

Should I be including each of these explicitly in my component? Apart from "map", I don't use them explicitly in my project. These are probably being called from within map or another Rx method.

UPDATE

I updated my Gulp script to copy all the Rx libraries and folders instead of just the single bundle file. It fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the `Rx.js` or `Rx.min.js` file from the `node_modules/rxjs/bundles` folder not `node_modules/rxjs` folder.

Otherwise you need to configure Rxjs in the SystemJS configuration:

```
System.config({
  map: {
    'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs',
    (...)
  },
  packages: {
    (...)
  }
});
```

Comment: I have a Gulp step that copies from node_modules to a lib folder. This is something that I had to do to get it to work in Visual Studio. Is there a difference in the Rx.js files between these different folders?

As for the System.config suggestion, I read somewhere that it is no longer necessary for the latest version. I might be mistaken. I'll give it a try.

Comment: From tour error messages, the js extension is missing... I think that you should add an rxjs entry in the packages block of your systemjs configuration to define: defaultExtension: 'js'.

Comment: I already have that. I updated my post above to include System config.

Answer (score 0):

Did you imported it the right way? Try this way.

```
import {Subject, Observable} from 'rxjs';
```

Comment: I don't use Subject or Observable within my component. Will I still need to do it anyway?

Comment: I would try to do it this way.

import * from 'rxjs';

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't accept *. I'm getting build errors.